# Sort XML data and apply an XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following XSLT and XML:

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                >
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          .exceed{background:yellow;}
          table{border-collapse:collapse;
          cellspacing:0px;
          cellpadding:5px;
          width:90%;}
          .total-hours{background-color:#808080;}
          .total-row-text{font-weight:bold;} 
          .report-header{background-color:#C6BD94;}
          /*{background-color:#FFFFBB;

          }*/
          .Report { width: 90%; font-family:Cambria,serif; font-size:14px  }
          .Report th { border: solid 1px }
          .Report td { padding:5px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; border: solid 1px }
          tr{background-color:#FFFFBB;}
        </style>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div class='ReportDescription'>
        </div>
        <div class='ReportDate'>
        </div>
        <table class="Report">
          <tr class="report-header">
            <xsl:for-each select="headers/header">

              <th class="report-Header">
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
              </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="Gray" select="PreviousDays/Employee[@total]">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="normal" select="PreviousDays/Employee[not(@total)]">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="PreviousDays/Employee" mode="Gray">       
    <tr class="total-hours">
      <td class="total-row-text">
        <xsl:value-of select="WorkingDate"/>
      </td>
      <td class="total-row-text">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
      </td>

      <td class="total-row-text">
        <xsl:value-of select="totalhours"/>
      </td>
      <td class="total-row-text">
        <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template mode="normal" match="PreviousDays/Employee">

    <tr class="exceed">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="WorkingDate"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
      </td>

      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="HoursOnProject"/>
      </td>         
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Department"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML**

```
<root>
  <headers>
    <header><title>Header1</title></header>
    <header><title>Header2</title></header>
    <header><title>Header3</title></header>
    <header><title>Header4</title></header>
  </headers>
  <PreviousDays>
    <Employee  Name="Martin Davis">
      <WorkingDate>9/12/2013</WorkingDate>
      <HoursOnProject>8</HoursOnProject>
      <Description>Description here</Description>
    </Employee>
    <Employee total="true" Name="Martin Davis">
      <WorkingDate>9/12/2013</WorkingDate>
      <HoursOnProject></HoursOnProject>
      <Description>Description here</Description>
      <totalhours>8</totalhours>
    </Employee>
    <Employee Name="Caroline Jackson">
      <WorkingDate>9/15/2013</WorkingDate>
      <HoursOnProject>8.50</HoursOnProject>
      <Description>Description here</Description>
    </Employee>
    <Employee total="true" Name="Caroline Jackson">
      <WorkingDate>9/15/2013</WorkingDate>
      <HoursOnProject></HoursOnProject>
      <Description>Description here</Description>
      <totalhours>10</totalhours>
    </Employee>
  </PreviousDays>
</root>
```

How can I make sure that the data is sorted or grouped together by the name attribute and WorkingDate so that the total row for each individual record appears directly after any normal row? Preferably without using for-each or if type statements.  (Those types of solutions are welcome though.)

Desired output

```
<table class="Report">
      <tr class="report-header">
        <th class="report-Header">Header1</th>
        <th class="report-Header">Header2</th>
        <th class="report-Header">Header3</th>
        <th class="report-Header">Header4</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="exceed">
        <td>9/12/2013</td>
        <td>Martin Davis</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="total-hours">
        <td class="total-row-text">9/12/2013</td>
        <td class="total-row-text">Martin Davis</td>
        <td class="total-row-text">8</td>
        <td class="total-row-text">Description here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="exceed">
        <td>9/15/2013</td>
        <td>Caroline Jackson</td>
        <td>8.50</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="total-hours">
        <td class="total-row-text">9/15/2013</td>
        <td class="total-row-text">Caroline Jackson</td>
        <td class="total-row-text">10</td>
        <td class="total-row-text">Description here</td>
      </tr>    
    </table>
```

Note that I don't want to switch to *XSLT 2.0* if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

<!-- Employee without @total grouped by Name  -->
<xsl:key name="employees-by-name" match="/root/PreviousDays/Employee[not(@total)]" use="@Name" />
<!-- Employee with @total grouped by Name  -->
<xsl:key name="employees-total-by-name" match="/root/PreviousDays/Employee[@total]" use="@Name" />

<!-- templates for writting the trs -->
<xsl:template match="Employee" mode="css-class">
  <tr class="exceed">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="contents" />
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Employee[@total='true']" mode="css-class">
  <tr class="total-hours">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="contents" />
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<!-- template for writting the tds -->
<xsl:template match="Employee" mode="contents">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="WorkingDate"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="HoursOnProject"/></td>         
  <td><xsl:value-of select="Department"/></td>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/root">
  <html>
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
      .exceed{background:yellow;}
      table{border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0px;cellpadding:5px;width:90%;}
      .total-hours td{background-color:#808080;font-weight:bold;}
      .report-header{background-color:#C6BD94;}
      .Report {width: 90%; font-family:Cambria,serif; font-size:14px;}
      .Report th {border: solid 1px;}
      .Report td {padding:5px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; border: solid 1px;}
      tr{background-color:#FFFFBB;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class='ReportDescription'>
      </div>
      <div class='ReportDate'>
      </div>
      <table class="Report">
        <tr class="report-header">
          <xsl:for-each select="headers/header">
            <th class="report-Header">
              <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </th>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- loop for each Employee which does not have a preceding-sibling with same @Name -->
        <xsl:for-each select="PreviousDays/Employee[not(@Name = preceding-sibling::Employee/@Name)]">
          <!-- apply templates for those elements with same @Name and not @total attribute -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('employees-by-name',@Name)" mode="css-class">
            <xsl:sort select="WorkingDate" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
          <!-- apply templates for those -or that- elements with same @Name and with @total attribute -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('employees-total-by-name',@Name)" mode="css-class" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```